# Fatou, Dominated Convergence, etc. for nets (in relation to stochastic processes)

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

In textbooks on Stochastic Processes, they always seem to assume that Fatou and DCT etc. can be applied to continuous-time stochastic processes $(X_{t})_{t\in\mathbb{R}_{+}}$. But in every book on measure theory that I know of, these theorems are only proved for (countable) sequences of functions.

Is there a simple reason that justifies this transition?

It's easy to see that the theorems do not generalize immediately to nets, so this cannot be the whole answer. For example, we can construct a net by indicator functions converging to the indicator of a non lebesgue measurable set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick to apply DCT or similar statements is  following:

Let's stay tou want to show $\int X_t \rightarrow \int X$ as $t \rightarrow a$. If you show this for every sequence $t_n \rightarrow a$, then you are done. In this case you are reduced to the more familiar situation.

You can also consider this by proof by contradiction. If such a statement didn't hold, then for every $\epsilon_n$ you would get a $t_n$ such that something goes wrong.. Then consider those $X_{t_n}'s$. But by DCT (or whatever you are using) things can't go wrong for a sequence- hence contradiction.

I have to be a bit vague, as I don't have any particular example of what you are trying to show- but these are some ways that you can prove these sort of statements.

Comment: So you'd handle DCT like this: $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}f_{t}=f$
 , and $\left|f_{t}\right|\leq g$
 . Then certainly $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{t_{n}}=f$
  for any sequence $t_{n}\rightarrow\infty$
 . In particular, $f$
  is measurable. Hence DCT yields $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int f_{t_{n}}\mbox{d}\mu=\int f\mbox{d}\mu$
  for any such sequence. Since $t_{n}\rightarrow\infty$
  was arbitrary (and we're in euclidean space), this implies $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int f_{t_{n}}\mbox{d}\mu=\int f\mbox{d}\mu$.

Comment: @ProbStudent: That's right.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I was really thinking in terms of whether you could generalize to nets under some easy assumptions. But your answer gives me the justification I was looking for.

Comment: @ProbStudent: Glad to help. I had also thought about the justifications (in a different context), and so I happened to know the answer.

Comment: It's maybe worth emphasizing that it's key that we're in euclidean space, where sequences are sufficient to detect limits. Otherwise convergence for countable subnets (which is all DCT gives us) would not suffice to conclude $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int f_{t}\mbox{d}\mu=\int f\mbox{d}\mu$ in the last step of my first comment.